# How do I always force a rerun of a job defined as a dependency (Gitlab CI/CD)

Tags: gitlab-ci.yml

My problem is basically this:

I have a `build` job and a `deploy` job in my gitlab-ci.yml.

```
build:
  extends: .node_base
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - artifact_folder
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm start

deploy:
  tags:
    - linux-docker
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  script:
    - aws --endpoint-url $AWS_HOST s3 sync artifact_folder/ s3://$AWS_S3_BUCKET --delete --acl public-read
  dependencies:
    - build
```

The `build` job downloads files from an external location and saves them in an artifact for my `deploy` job to use.

The `deploy` takes the files from the `build` job artifact and uploads them to an s3 bucket.

So far so good. The problem is that everytime I want to deploy new changes I will have to first re-run the `build` job to get the updated files from the external location, before I re-run the `deploy` job.
Its not a big issue but I would like to, if possible, only have one job that does both the build step and the deploy step.

My first idea was to simply run the `- npm start` in the `build` job as a `before_script` in the `deploy` job. However, I am limited by the infrastructure setup by devops atm, which means the build job runs on an environment where `npm` is installed, and the `deploy` job runs on an environment where `npm` is not installed.

Is there anyway I can run these two jobs separately, but somehow also only need one button in gitlab to start both of these scripts.
Or perhaps force the `build` job to always re-run before the `deploy` job runs, or vice versa. And disable the `deploy` job from being able to run independently of the `build` job?

Comment: Why don't you create a bash script for this purpose. Or you can try something like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cmd-try-catch

Comment: I can't install dependencies on the runners. And it can't be something I run locally as non-developers need to be able to click the play-button in gitlab to make new deploys by themselves.