# How to retrigger a successful gitlab child pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, cicd

Is there a way of retriggering a successful child pipeline in gitlab ? I don't see any retry button in trigger job, which we otherwise see in normal pipline job. Is there a way/workaround to get an option to do so ?

I went through the gitlab doc, it only talks about retrying failed jobs in child pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

That is currently (Q4 2022) not supported yet.
(And [`retry:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#retry) is indeed only for failed job)

It is requested by [issue 29456](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/29456):

> ### Ability to rerun a successful pipeline via "Retry" button
>
> Not only failed pipelines sometimes need a rerun but also successful ones:
>
> - If your tests are unreliable and you are sceptical that the test success is repeatable
> - If your jobs depend on outside factors
> - If your job depends on some predefined CI variable which can change without a code change
>
> So in general, a pipeline should show the retry button even in case of a success. Then, all jobs should be retried again
>
> The currently suggested workaround of `CI / CD -> Pipelines -> Run Pipeline` does not always work, especially not for merge request pipelines.
> In my case, I have all jobs defined as `only: merge_requests` and "`Run Pipeline`" responds with the error "`No stages / jobs for this pipeline`"

Comment: Other use cases: [issue 3450](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/3450) or ["How do I always force a rerun of a job defined as a dependency (Gitlab CI/CD)"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72511382/6309).